# Google chrome wont ask for my location - html/ js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to access the users location via js. The code seems to work fine but not on chrome. When coding it, chrome would notify me that its trying to access my location but as I was running it from a file, I couldn't allow it. On IE it did let me allow it and it worked just fine.

I quickly uploaded it to a free hosting site to test it on chrome and now it doesn't even acknowledge that it wants my location, it's like the function doesn't even run. I run it on IE and that works perfectly fine.

Code:

```
Date.prototype.Today = function () { 
return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
}

Date.prototype.Time = function () {
 return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
}

var DateTime = new Date().Today() + " " + new Date().Time();
var Latitude = "Unavailable";
var Longitude = "Unavailable";

IP = GetIP("https://api.ipify.org/");
initGeolocation();

function GetIP(theUrl)
{
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

  function initGeolocation()
  {
if( navigator.geolocation )
{
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success); 
}
  }

 function success(position)
 {
 Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 document.write(DateTime + " " + IP + " " + Latitude + " " + Longitude);
 }

 document.write(DateTime + " " + IP + " " + Latitude + " " + Longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Settings

Click Show advanced settings.

In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.

In the dialog that appears, scroll down to the "Location" section. Select your default permission for future location requests:

Allow all sites to track your physical location: Select this option to let all sites automatically access your location.

Comment: i did that, other sites can access it fine, its just this one on chrome, it doesnt even come up that its tryna access it